# Question on Memory Issues in Android

Tags: android, memory

Will there be a memory issue if we use lot of frame by frame animation in android

Comment: Memory management should be a consideration in all mobile development projects. Frame by frame animation will almost certainly require some level of memory management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends entirely upon how you implement it, and details such as how large your frames are and what kind of color-depth you choose to use.  In general, however, you should be able to come up with a rendering algorithm that doesn't hold references to more than a handful of frames at any one point in time.

Ideally you should only need a reference to the previous frame and your working buffer for the current frame.  Assuming that's the case, and assuming that you're using 8-bit RGBA pixel encoding, then you can easily work out how approximately much memory your animation will consume when running.  It's:

`frame.width * frame.height * 4 * 2` bytes

And then from that you can make a reasonable estimate of whether or not your device can meet your memory requirements.  As a general rule, as long as your frames are not larger than your device resolution you should be okay.